# finding if the current working browser is safari via css or javascript

Tags: css, safari

I researched on identifying, if the browser is Safari or not.
In `javascript` :  `window.devicePixelRatio` object gives '1' for both chrome and safari
In `CSS` :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    #yourdiv{
        margin-left:0;

    }
}
```

It works for both chrome and safari. But I didn't find css or javascript hack for safari browser only (shouldn't work for any other browser). Can any body help me out.

I am using the safari brower: 
     navigator.useragent = `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/) && ! navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/)) {
   alert('this is safari brower and only safari brower')
}
```

Answer (score 7):

CSS hacks are frowned upon, though less frowned upon when targeting older versions of IE (a necessary evil).

You could figure out if using Safari like this...

#### JavaScript

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/OS X.*Safari/) && ! navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/)) {
   document.body.className += 'safari';
}
```

...and then use modify your selectors for Safari like so...

#### CSS

```
.safari #yourdiv {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/k6tjc/).

Comment: @alex The previous one worked, but for both safari and chrome browser.And
`/OS X.*Safari/ ` didn't worked out

Comment: @Prakash See updated, it now only matches Safari (not Chrome).

Comment: I looked at jsfiddle's link that u've given, it's not working.. the background is red

Comment: @Prakash What version of Safari are you using? It worked in my 5.0.3. Also, can you post your `navigator.userAgent` ?

Comment: I've posted on my question navigator.useragent

Comment: I've tried with changing your code. I replaced `(/OS X.*Safari/)` to `(/AppleWebKit/)` and it worked fine. +1 vote up for your help

Answer (score 2):

There's a javascript function that helps identify most browsers [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).

Its worth keeping up to date on, as it is updating regularly.

By way of explanation the following is copied from the linked page:

---

Browser detection

The dataBrowser array is filled with objects that contain the properties that help the script detect your users' browser. Note its general syntax:

```
dataBrowser: [
    {
        prop: window.opera,
        identity: "Opera",
        versionSearch: "Version" // note: no comma
    },
    {
        string: navigator.userAgent,
        subString: "MSIE",
        identity: "Explorer",
        versionSearch: "MSIE" // note: no comma
    } // note: no comma
];
```

The [] define an array literal, and all of its elements are object literals. Each object literal is enclosed in curly braces {} and contains a few properties (name: value,). Note that a comma between the objects and between the properties is required, but that the last comma is always forbidden.

Properties

Every object in the dataBrowser array can contain the following properties:

string and subString properties. These say: "search for subString in string". If the subString is found, the browser is identified.
a prop property. It says "see if prop is supported". If it is, the browser is identified.
an identity string. This string becomes the value of BrowserDetect.browser.
a versionSearch string. This is for searching for the version number (see below). If this property is absent, the identity string is used instead.
Every object must contain either 1 or 2 (never both!), must contain 3 and may contain 4.

Comment: Yes that worked, but I don't want to put all those long javascript codes on my project. anyway I find out one line solution. Thanks for help with my +1 vote.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but all the answers provided will detect both desktop and mobile Safari. To detect only one or the other, you can use this:

```
var inDesktopSafari = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') === -1) && typeof window.ontouchstart === 'undefined';

var inMobileSafari = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') === -1) && typeof window.ontouchstart !== 'undefined';
```

Comment: So long as Apple don't come out with a touch-enabled desktop device.