# jquery safari opacity only

Tags: jquery, css, safari, opacity

```
#div1{ 
filter:alpha(opacity=85); 
-moz-opacity:0.85; 
-khtml-opacity:0.85; 
opacity: 0.85;
}

#div1:hover{ 
filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
-moz-opacity:1; 
-khtml-opacity:1; 
opacity: 1;
}

html>#div1.safarihack{
opacity: 1; 
}
```

All the above does as intended. Safari always has its opacity set to full because it doesnt render properly if not.  However, i also have a jquery event that when this div is clicked, the opacity fades to 0, and i need it to fade to 0 for all browsers (fadeout is not an option).

The html of the div is then changed, and i need the opacity for all browsers to return to 0.85 or 85, except for safari, which needs to go back to 100.

How can i target this in the jquery? Is there some way i can put

```
html>#div1.safarihack {opacity: 1; }
```

into this?

```
$(this).html(nextHtml).animate({'opacity':'0.85',
                                              'filter':'alpha(opacity=85)', 
                                              '-moz-opacity':'0.85',
                                              '-khtml-opacity':'0.85',
                                              }, 500);
```

****Note that (this) = #div1*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [finding if the current working browser is safari via css or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298686/finding-if-the-current-working-browser-is-safari-via-css-or-javascript) : could help you, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this thread interesting: [Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).html(nextHtml).animate({opacity:($.browser.safari)?1:.85});
```

Note that `$.browser.safari` is deprecated.

There's also no need to use all those opacity-attributes in jQuery, jQuery will translate "opacity" to the attribute the current browser is supporting.

Answer (score 0):

Does **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q948F/3/)** help with your problem? I lowered the opacity to make the hover more obvious for the demo.

**Edit: [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q948F/5/)** in which the text opacity changes. Seems to work OK in Safari5

I don't really understand the problem with Safari opacity as I am not seeing any problems running the demo in Safari5, Chrome12 or Firefox4.

Comment: your code is the same as what i was trying. if i viewed your demo in safari it worked, and if i viewed mine it didnt. iv solved it now another way but cheers for your help, still not sure why it didnt work though.